# Software to automatically download Youtube videos

Tags: software-recommendation, youtube

I'm looking for (free) Ubuntu YouTube software that can perform two tasks (could be separate software):

- display on screen notification (like transmission does when a download has finished) when a new video has been uploaded to your personal subscription box
- download videos in max quality (preferably automatically once a new video has been uploaded from specific channels / series)

What I've found so far:

- [All Video Downloader](http://www.kastorsoft.com/index_en.php): only downloads manually, can't select quality
- [MiniTube](http://flavio.tordini.org/forums/forum/minitube-forums): Doesn't associate with your personal account, doesn't notify when new video has been uploaded from your subscriptions. Annoying GUI. Quite buggy.

If this software doesn't exist yet, I'll try to make it myself.

Comment: See this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/flareget-is-great-download-manager-for.html)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the first, but the second can be easily done with [`youtube-dl`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/youtube-dl):

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

I've copied the help text about formating here:

```
Video Format Options:
    -f, --format FORMAT        video format code, specifiy the order of
                               preference using slashes: "-f 22/17/18"
    --all-formats              download all available video formats
    --prefer-free-formats      prefer free video formats unless a specific one
                               is requested
    --max-quality FORMAT       highest quality format to download
    -F, --list-formats         list all available formats (currently youtube
                           only)
```

So you can use `--max-quality` to get the maximum quality format. On a personal note, I find `youtube-dl` very easy to use (I just type yo and <kbd>Tab</kbd> in terminal and it auto-completes it for me). It can also download every video by a specific channel and has a multitude of options.

I believe you can set it to continue downloads with the `-c` option and if you do that for a channel, it *should* download only new ones if in the same directory as the others were downloaded to, but have not tried it in practice. If you can, then you can run `youtube-dl` on a script and it will only download the files when there are new ones.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. It seems `--download-archive FILENAME_HERE` is now how you only download "new" videos. youtube-dl will not download any file not listed in the archive, and will add each new download's name to to the archive. 
To run a command once per day: `while sleep 86400; do COMMAND_HERE ; done`